# Parsing XML in pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have a list of xml files, and I want to get two values in each of these files to create an index for a dataframe. I do this using a for loop since I have roughly 1000 files, which isn't that big, and I want to compute some features on these files to store in the dataframe.

For example, the first file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag3>
            <author>The author</author>
            <title> The title </title>
        </tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

So I can create a dataframe with the multi-index `[author,title]` with:

```
tree = etree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
title = tree.xpath("/tag1/tag2/tag3/author")[0].text
author = tree.xpath("/tag1/tag2/tag3/title")[0].text

features = [Some Feature engineering]
features_names = [List of the feature names]
pd.DataFrame(features,columns = features_names,index = [[author],[title]])
```

My problem is that, as the structure is always the same among the files (same number of tags), the name of the tags can change from one file to another, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag_1>
    <secondtag>
        <tag3>
            <author>The second author</author>
            <title> The second title </title>
        </tag3>
    </secondtag>
</tag_1>
```

How can I then access the author and title not knowing in advance the names of the tags?

Comment: If they're always author and title tags - just search for those anywhere? eg: `.xpath('//author')` ?

Comment: I do always have the `author` and title `tag`, but when I tried your way, it didn't work, I got `list index out of range` since `tree.xpath('//author')` returned an empty list. Nonetheless, I've seen that the incriminated file is the first to have the first tag with: `<tag1 xmlns="some_url">`. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Ahhh.... so you'll want to change the xpath to include the namespace then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find child nodes instead of direct paths
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree